# Eclipse Debug run and console run of the same program give different outputs

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, cout, eclipse-cdt

So this is in reference to my older question which I fixed.

Now the issue is that when I run my program (code as follows)...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include "timesync.h"

FILE * CTimeSync::pipe = NULL;

int CTimeSync::TimeSyncCheck()
{
    char szPipeBuffer [200];
    string strPipeOutput;

    memset( szPipeBuffer, 0, sizeof(szPipeBuffer) );

    CTimeSync::pipe = popen( "ntpq -np", "r" );
    if ( CTimeSync::pipe )
    {
        while ( !feof( CTimeSync::pipe ) )
        {
            if ( fgets( szPipeBuffer, 200, CTimeSync::pipe ) != NULL )
            {
//              memset( szPipeBuffer, 0, sizeof(szPipeBuffer) );
                strPipeOutput.append(szPipeBuffer);
            }
        }

        pclose(CTimeSync::pipe);
    }

    cout << strPipeOutput;
    cout << "abc\npqr\nxyz\n123" << endl; //test string
    return 1; //ERROR
}
```

the run putputs for eclipse debug mode and that in the console (linux) are different.

eclipse run in both eclipse console and redirected to terminal.

```
     remote           refid          st   t  when poll reach    delay    offset  jitter
abc
pqr
xyz
123
```

Terminal run (./main)

```
     remote           refid          st   t  when poll reach    delay    offset  jitter
=======================================================================================
*10.92.1.200       LOCAL(1) ...
abc
pqr
xyz
123
```

what is causing this?

Comment: Looks like you have some dangling pointer, or unintentionally overwritten memory here. I'd recommend to analyze your program using a debugger.

Comment: Sorry for being daft, but can you tell me how? I did try stepping through the code, seems to be running as intended, since strPipeOutput contains the same values in either runs which is the one shown in terminal run. Only the cout seems to be giving different results. Or maybe I am doing something wrong, very very worg.

Comment: since strPipeOutput is the same, but appears differently on output, have you checked it for non-printable characters, specifically carriage return (without newline)?

Comment: Ok so I did another experiment to print out the size of both strings before the print, and in both run scenarios the size is 237.

I put a watch on the strPipeOutput and turns out the there is a newline character after"jitter" i.e. '\n' (ASCII code 10), no carriage return.

Comment: I can't say more than that I reproduce the same behaviour in my gnome terminal/bash: "hello\012world" outputs "hello" in the terminal window and "hello" above "world" in the eclipse output window.

Comment: Guys I can reproduce the issue at least, or rather I know what is the issue. still dont know why that is and what's causing it.

The substring after line feed "\n=*123" is causing the problem. Now I dont know any escape characters for this nature but if there is a special case that your guys know of, please do tell.