# cout behaving unexpectedly for specific strings

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, terminal

This question is an extension to this one.
[Eclipse Debug run and console run of the same program give different outputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930546/eclipse-debug-run-and-console-run-of-the-same-program-give-different-outputs)

To give a bit of background...
While parsing the output of the NTP application I discovered something rather odd in my string outputs. The environment that I am using is eclipse with CDT in Debug mode, redirecting console output to a terminal (/dev/pts/0) with fish running as shell.

Where is what I found...
Strings with starting characters or charachter within like *, +, &, ^. such as when I try to cout like this.

```
cout << "+123" << endl; //does not get printed
cout << "*123" << endl; //does not get printed
cout << "&123" << endl; //Concatenates with string below (without the line feed)
cout << "|123" << endl; //^
cout << "^123" << endl; //Does not get printed
```

Also

```
cout << "abcdef" << endl << endl;
```

does not have the desired effect of two linefeeds; only one gets printed.

Whereas when I run the progam through the terminal...

```
~$ ./Project/Debug/Project
```

Everything is normal and works as expected.

Is this expected behaviour, something I am not aware of?
Or is this a bug, corruption or something if such nature?
Or am I doing something wrong?

P.S: I might have left some details out by accident, please read the question in the link provided about to catch up.

Comment: What happens if you run the binary on a terminal directly, not through Eclipse?

Comment: "with fish running as shell" ??? What?

Comment: cdhowie: works fine. as expected.

Comment: BJobnn: Is that an issue? could that be causing the prolem.

Comment: @user1662075 Then it sounds like an Eclipse bug.

Comment: @cdhowie: A bug or a corruption?

Just to put everything out there, I am running all of this on cubieboard running debian. so It could be a memory leak or overrun as well?

Comment: What happens if you redirect from Eclipse to a regular file instead? What happens if you echo these strings from a shell in another terminal and redirect to your pts?

Comment: Hmmm have not tried the file or redirecting... but I ll try that out.

But in the debug mode when I step through the code, the strings remain intact and are correct in contents and size. (see the link). I ve even compared the strings with presets and they return true. So I dont think the issue is with the strings. The file idea might tell us if the issue is retricted to ostream or behaves the same in fstream?

Comment: @user1662075 Corruption is (IMO) far less likely than a bug in output handling in an IDE.